# Access other user's local application settings in C#

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-3.5, impersonation, settings

I have WPF application, let's say **Application1**, run under **User1**. I need to access user scoped settings of **User2** in AppData folder for **Application2**.

So, what's really happening is this:

- **User1** is logged in user, in windows
- **User1** is actually person associated with account **User2**
- **User1** starts **Application1**
- **Application1** asks for credentials to ensures **User1** starts application (see next bullet) as appropriate user (**User2** in this case)
- Now, **Application1** should run **Application2** with provided credentials, but before that, it should check **User2** settings for **Application2**

How can I do that without running **Application1** as **User2**?

If I can change process owner for **Application1** at run time to do that, that would also be acceptable  solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running another custom made console program under User2 which reads settings file as XmlDocument.

Reading settings file:

```
if (File.Exists(settingsPath))
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(settingsPath);
    XmlNode settingsNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/XPath.to.node.you.are.looking.for");
    foreach(XmlNode xmlNode in settingsNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        //do some work
    }
}
```